# Can't install MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I installed `mariadb-server` before installing `mysql-server` (which I wasn't supposed to do), so I purged `mariadb*` and removed it from the repos. However, I can't install `mysql-server`.

After `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, I get:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                     [ OK ] update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                     [ OK ] invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-2) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (1.71-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.26-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl (0.77-1build1) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.10-1) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.11-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After running `sudo apt-get install -f`, I get:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.19-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                     [ OK ] Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                                                                     [ OK ] invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I get around these errors and install `mysql-server`?

Comment: Did you `stop` maria db before purging it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems mariadb not removed/purged completely.

```
 sudo apt-get purge mariadb* 
 sudo apt-get purge mysql* 
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Remove everything in /etc/mysql directory

```
 rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

Now insatll mysql-server

```
apt-get install mysql-server
```

If above steps still showing any error then try to reconfigure dpkg

```
dpkg --configure -a
```